# C++ correcting the position for point(x,y) on the graph

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I am working on graphic calculator with [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc/). First I ask the user to enter how many point does he want on the graph and then I ask him for the point(X,Y) and then graph it.

The problem is when I put the point(X,Y),  it position  on the corner of the screen

**Example**: I put 50 for X and 30 for Y, P(50,30); The answer that I get back is 
[image]

This is the Code I have:

```
void ofApp::drawCircle(int x, int y){
    ofSetColor(0,0,0);
    ofCircle(x,y,10);
}
void ofApp::ofSetBackgroundColor(){
    ofBackgroundGradient(ofColor::white, ofColor::gray);
}
void ofApp::writeText(){

    ofSetColor(252,5,5);
    ofDrawBitmapString("X axis",500,690);
    ofDrawBitmapString("0   10   20    30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100   110   120   130   140   150  ",100,670);
    ofDrawBitmapString("Y axis",20,450);
    ofDrawBitmapString("10",70,610);
    ofDrawBitmapString("20",70,570);
    ofDrawBitmapString("30",70,530);
    ofDrawBitmapString("40",70,490);
    ofDrawBitmapString("50",70,450);
    ofDrawBitmapString("60",70,410);
    ofDrawBitmapString("70",70,370);
    ofDrawBitmapString("80",70,330);
    ofDrawBitmapString("90",70,290);
    ofDrawBitmapString("100",70,250);
    ofDrawBitmapString("110",70,210);
    ofDrawBitmapString("120",70,170);
    ofDrawBitmapString("130",70,130);
    ofDrawBitmapString("140",70,90);
    ofDrawBitmapString("150",70,50); 
}
void ofApp::DrawlineX(){
    ofSetColor(252,5,5);
    ofLine(100,30,100,650);
    ofSetColor(252,5,5);
    ofLine(100,650,750,650);
    ofSetColor(0,0,0);
    ofLine(100,650,750,270);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::update(){

}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::draw(){
    ofSetBackgroundColor();
    writeText();
    DrawlineX();

    if(pos==0){
    for(int i=0;i<TotoalDots;i++){
        drawCircle(arryX[i],arryY[i]);
    }
    }else{

        drawCircle(myX,myY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues that you need to take into consideration:

- Y axis is flipped in images. Means `(0, 0)` is the top left corner, and `(0, max)` is the bottom left corner
- You need to take into consideration the position of `(0, 0)` on your graph (not the image's), and then add it to your point.

Therefore, if your `(0, 0)` is at `(100, 100)`, then point `(50, 30)` would be  at `(100 + 50, 100 - 30)`

Comment: this is what i did  get ofGetHeight()/2-myX,ofGetWidth()/2-myY, it movies the point to the middle of the graph but when i put new points, the position stay the same thing as the previous one

Comment: Thank you @Kyle Khalaf figure it out